# Where does ASP.NET Identity store information about external authentication provider?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have enabled authentication using Microsoft and Google accounts. They both are working fine. i.e., I am able to login to my application using my hotmail and gmail both accounts.

Once logged in (say, using Microsoft account), I am able to see following screen as well.

[image]

I am able to change the password. While all this works fine, I am quite unsure where all this information is getting stored? In previous editions, I was able to see External Provider mapping tables getting created automatically in the database. However, in this instance, database has no table, which makes me believe that this mapping is getting stored somewhere else.

Can someone please shed lights on this?

P.S. - I am using SQL Server 2016 Express edition, and have no other authentication enabled for this application (i.e., there is no Forms authentication as well). Only, Google and Microsoft logins are accepted.
Also, System.Web.Mvc in my application is of version - 5.2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in the AspNetUserLogins table.

[image: Asp.net Identity tables]

Comment: This was the case earlier. I think this is changed in later releases of MVC. I was expecting AspNetUserLogins table, but it is not there in the database. In fact, my database is having no table!